# add markers googlemap with javascript since JSON external

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

external JSON:

```js
{
    "playas": [
        {
            "nombre": "Laredo",
            "ubicacion": {
                "municipio": {
                    "nombre": "Laredo",
                    "codigoPostal": 39035
                },
                "latitud": 43.419746,
                "longitud": -3.453788
            },
            "descripcion": {
                "detalle": "De entorno urbano y de 5000 metros de extensión es la playa de Laredo con un alto grado de ocupación en la época estival.",
                "fondo": "Arena",
                "mar": "Fuerte",
                "vientos": [
                    {
                        "viento": "S"
                    },
                    {
                        "viento": "SO"
                    },
                    {
                        "viento": "NO"
                    }
                ],
                "marea": "Subiendo",
                "tamaño": "1-1.5",
                "olas": [
                    {
                        "nombre": "El Espigón",
                        "descripcion": "derecha potente con fondo de lastra"
                    },
                    {
                        "nombre": "La Playa",
                        "descripcion": "buenas derechas"
                    }
                ],
                "nivel": "medio"
            },
            "foto": "img/playas/laredo.jpg"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "Berria",
            "ubicacion": {
                "municipio": {
                    "nombre": "Santoña",
                    "codigoPostal": 39079
                },
                "latitud": 43.465348,
                "longitud": -3.450717
            },
            "descripcion": {
                "detalle": "Playa de aproximadamente 2 kilómetros de arena que se encuentra en un entorno semi-urbano mezclado con áreas verdes y pequeñas dunas. En verano mucha afluencia.",
                "fondo": "Arena",
                "mar": "Fuerte",
                "vientos": [
                    {
                        "viento": "S"
                    },
                    {
                        "viento": "SO"
                    },
                    {
                        "viento": "NO"
                    }
                ],
                "marea": "Subiendo",
                "tamaño": "1-1.5",
                "olas": [
                    {
                        "nombre": "Variables",
                        "descripcion": ""
                    }
                ],
                "nivel": "medio"
            },
            "foto": "img/playas/berria.jpg"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "El Brusco",
            "ubicacion": {
                "municipio": {
                    "nombre": "Noja",
                    "codigoPostal": 39047
                },
                "latitud": 43.476887,
                "longitud": -3.512989
            },
            "descripcion": {
                "detalle": "También llamado Helgueras y ubicado al final de la Playa de Trengandín. Se llega a través de un camino mal asfaltado desde Noja. Hay que caminar por la playa para ver su verdadero “poderío”. En verano mucha afluencia.",
                "fondo": "Arena",
                "mar": "Fuerte",
                "vientos": [
                    {
                        "viento": "S"
                    }
                ],
                "marea": "Subiendo",
                "tamaño": "2",
                "olas": [
                    {
                        "nombre": "Variables",
                        "descripcion": "Tanto derecha como izquierda potente. Rápidas y tuberas"
                    }
                ],
                "nivel": "experto"
            },
            "foto": "img/playas/elbrusco.jpg"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "Langre",
            "ubicacion": {
                "municipio": {
                    "nombre": "Ribamontán al Mar",
                    "codigoPostal": 39061
                },
                "latitud": 43.477961,
                "longitud": -3.695723
            },
            "descripcion": {
                "detalle": "Playa de unos 1.000 metros de longitud con un entorno de altos acantilados con accesos muy mejorados y en donde se practica al final de la playa el nudismo desde hace muchos años. Buen ambiente playero en verano.",
                "fondo": "Arena",
                "mar": "Medio",
                "vientos": [
                    {
                        "viento": "S"
                    },
                    {
                        "viento": "SO"
                    },
                    {
                        "viento": "E"
                    }
                ],
                "marea": "Subiendo",
                "tamaño": "1",
                "olas": [
                    {
                        "nombre": "Variables",
                        "descripcion": "divertido para pasar un buen rato, control para no llevarse a nadie por delante"
                    }
                ],
                "nivel": "bajo"
            },
            "foto": "img/playas/langre.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

and the javascript where i read the JSON and add the markers with latitude and longitud for each object

```js
var READY_STATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0; //No inicializado objeto creado, pero no se ha invocado el metodo open
var READY_STATE_LOADING = 1; //Cargando objeto creado pero no se ha invocado el metodo send
var READY_STATE_LOADED = 2; //Cargado se ha invocado el metodo send, pero el servidor aún no ha respondido
var READY_STATE_INTERACTIVE = 3; //Interactivo se ha recibido algunos datos, aunque no se puede emplear la propiedad
var READY_STATE_COMPLETE = 4;//Se ha recibido todos los datos
var peticion_http;
var documento_json;
var playasJson = [];

function initialize() {
  

    var options = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng("43.597436","-3.653516"),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('contenedorMapa'), options);
    setMarkers(map,playasJson);
    
};


function rellenarJson(playas)
{
    //Preguntar a fernando poruqe tienen ubicacion0 si ordenados tienen posicion 0 y el otro 1
    for (var i = 0; i < playas.length; i++) {
        playasJson.push({ 
            nombre:playas[i].nombre,
            lat:playas[i].ubicacion.latitud,
            long:playas[i].ubicacion.longitud
        });                    
    }
}

// Obtener la instancia del objeto XMLHttpRequest
function inicializa_xhr() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        return new ActiveXObject("Msxml3.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        return ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
}


//Mostrar la info del json
function  muestraContenido() {
    if (peticion_http.readyState === READY_STATE_COMPLETE) {
        if (peticion_http.status === 200) {
            documento_json = peticion_http.responseText;
            var objeto = eval("(" + documento_json + ")");
            var playasObtenidas = objeto.playas;
            rellenarJson(playasObtenidas);
        }

    }
}

//Llamar al json en una variable y añadir funcion
function cargarContenido(url, metodo, funcion)
{
    peticion_http = inicializa_xhr();
    if (peticion_http)
    {
        peticion_http.onreadystatechange = funcion;
        peticion_http.open(metodo, url, true);
        peticion_http.send(null);
    }
}


function descargaArchivo() {
    cargarContenido("json/listadoPlayas.json", "GET", muestraContenido);
}


function setMarkers(map,playasArray) {
    descargaArchivo();
    for (var k = 0; k < playasArray.length; k++) {
        var beach = playasArray[k];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach.lat,beach.long);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            //icon: image,
            //shape: shape,
            title: beach[0],
            zIndex: beach[3]
        });
    }
}




google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

and the html

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;language=es"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="map_1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="contenedorMapa" style="width: 100%;height: 900px;">TODO write content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

PLease someone know why doesn't work?? i don't know why?? thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's the json the server is sending back, it's bad formed. That could explain why the markers aren't showing up. You can check it's validity [here](http://jsonlint.com/).

In order to solve the problem, just add

```
 ]
}
```

at the end of your current json.

I've tested your code substituting the ajax calls by the json string with the fixes I mentioned and it works [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1batLssz/3/).

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

The problem is that the function that adds the markers gets called much before that the AJAX call is completed (remember that AJAX is asynchronous). That means that when you add markers, there are none in the array. You have to call the function that adds the markers once the AJAX call has finished and the array has been populated properly.

You could do something like this:

```
        var READY_STATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0; //No inicializado objeto creado, pero no se ha invocado el metodo open
        var READY_STATE_LOADING = 1; //Cargando objeto creado pero no se ha invocado el metodo send
        var READY_STATE_LOADED = 2; //Cargado se ha invocado el metodo send, pero el servidor aún no ha respondido
        var READY_STATE_INTERACTIVE = 3; //Interactivo se ha recibido algunos datos, aunque no se puede emplear la propiedad
        var READY_STATE_COMPLETE = 4;//Se ha recibido todos los datos
        var peticion_http;
        var documento_json;
        var playasJson = [];
        var map;

        function initialize() {


            var options = {
                zoom: 10,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng("43.597436", "-3.653516"),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('contenedorMapa'), options);
            descargaArchivo();
        }


        function rellenarJson(playas)
        {
            //Preguntar a fernando poruqe tienen ubicacion0 si ordenados tienen posicion 0 y el otro 1
            for (var i = 0; i < playas.length; i++) {
                playasJson.push({
                    nombre: playas[i].nombre,
                    lat: playas[i].ubicacion.latitud,
                    long: playas[i].ubicacion.longitud
                });
            }
            setMarkers(map, playasJson);
        }

        // Obtener la instancia del objeto XMLHttpRequest
        function inicializa_xhr() {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                return new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                return new ActiveXObject("Msxml3.XMLHTTP");
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                return ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        }


        //Mostrar la info del json
        function  muestraContenido() {
            if (peticion_http.readyState === READY_STATE_COMPLETE) {
                if (peticion_http.status === 200) {
                    documento_json = peticion_http.responseText;
                    var objeto = JSON.parse(documento_json);
                    var playasObtenidas = objeto.playas;
                    rellenarJson(playasObtenidas);
                }

            }
        }

        //Llamar al json en una variable y añadir funcion
        function cargarContenido(url, metodo, funcion)
        {
            peticion_http = inicializa_xhr();
            if (peticion_http)
            {
                peticion_http.onreadystatechange = funcion;
                peticion_http.open(metodo, url, true);
                peticion_http.send(null);
            }
        }


        function descargaArchivo() {
            cargarContenido("json/listadoPlayas.json", "GET", muestraContenido);
        }


        function setMarkers(map, playasArray) {

            for (var k = 0; k < playasArray.length; k++) {
                var beach = playasArray[k];
                var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(beach.lat, beach.long);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    //icon: image,
                    //shape: shape,
                    title: beach[0],
                    zIndex: beach[3]
                });
            }
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Rest of the code remains the same though I'd change that `eval(...)` to `JSON.parse(documento_json)`. You also have to remove the call to `descargaArchivo` from `setMarkers`

Comment: Sorry yes i had an error when i pasted here, i forget ]} at the end, the problem is when i call to JSON since the function "rellenarJson" and then i use the array variable "playasArray" in setMarkers(map,playasArray) doesn't work, i don´t know why work if i complete the array manually like you do it, and doesn´t work if i use a function to complete the array since the external json!! why??? thanks so much again!!

Comment: @MargaretFellerman ok, please check the update, now it's working here with the AJAX call.

Comment: Nothing, now doesn't appear the map inside de div! :(

Comment: @MargaretFellerman ok, copy and paste all my code. Here it works, but just in case check your console for errors. json/listadoPlayas.json must have the json string with the valid format and nothing more.

Comment: Yuuuuuhu now works perfect!!!!! thanks soooooooo much and thanks for explain me the reason for the order of the functions and why doesn't work, thanks for your help!!!